# Download GenBank sequence file within python script using only the accession number

Tags: python, fetch

Assume the input to a python script is a GenBank accession number such as n

.
How do I use only that accession number to download the file? I know I can use Bio::DB::EUtilities, but it seems to require  a ID.  Can the accession number be used instead of a numeric ID?
The code to download a file is

```
my @ids = qw(1621261 89318838 68536103 20807972 730439);

my $factory = Bio::DB::EUtilities->new(-eutil   => 'efetch',
                                       -db      => 'protein',
                                       -rettype => 'gb',
                                       -email   => 'mymail@foo.bar',
                                       -id      => \@ids);
```

The ids are all 7 digit numbers in the above example.
Can I set -id => AF405666.1 to fetch a single Genbank file?